# In iOS7, is it possible to add a custom keyboard to the system? Or is it still sandboxed?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I've seen online rumors from before iOS7's release about keyboards opening up.

I haven't found anything in the documentation.

Is it possible to add a custom keyboard, like emoji, to the system, in iOS 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add or change the system keyboard. However, you can implement your own custom keyboard inside your app. All you need to do is overwrite `UITextField` or `UITextView` and return a custom view for the `inputView` property.