# In app custom keyboard swift ios7/8

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard, custom-controls

Guides are everywhere on how to make a custom keyboard for phones using iOS8 and Swift, but I was wondering if I could create a custom keyboard in an app that would also be compatible with iOS7? I'd like to be able to switch to it from the default keyboard that comes up when a UITextfield is tapped. 

Would this answer be along the right track -
[In iOS7, is it possible to add a custom keyboard to the system? Or is it still sandboxed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901340/in-ios7-is-it-possible-to-add-a-custom-keyboard-to-the-system-or-is-it-still-s)
And if so, how would I create the custom keyboard?

Comment: This was always possible, even for before iOS 8. Any `UITextField` or `UITextView` has an `inputView` any view assigned to it would be displayed  instate of the normal keyboard. I've used it many time to create numeric keyboards for the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create custom keyboards *to the system*. You can always create custom keyboards for use inside your app, as @rckoenes said, but before iOS 8, everything was sandboxed.